# How to create current limiter to limit phone charging current to 500mA?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, current-limiting, iphone

I have this neat iPhone case from AudioMod (https://www.audiomod.com/audiomod) that has a built-in headphone jack.

[image: Audiomod board]

I'm looking to upgrade from my 6S to the latest iPhone SE, which is the iPhone 8 size. Audiomod doesn't make the 8 version any more, so all I have is this this board from a different-sized case. I'm going to take apart a different iPhone 8 case and put this board inside, and I also want to install a larger battery. The charging speed listed from this board is 1.5 A. Since the case is attached to the phone and not tethered to the wall, I see no need to charge that fast and would prefer to charge slower, around 500mA, to put less strain on the battery. Charging slower slows down how fast the battery degrades.

What is the best implementation to do this? I figured the easiest thing would be to use something like a PowerBoost 500 from Adafruit (https://www.adafruit.com/product/1903), but it seems like it draws up to 1A from a 3.7V li-ion/lipo which is more than I want. Would it be better to install the current limiter between the battery and the power input of the board (on the top) or between the power output and the lightning connector (on the bottom)? In the middle of the board there is a button with 4 LEDs to the right of it which are a voltage indicator for the battery, so if I attached the limiter (if it produces a constant 5V out) to the top terminals, I would lose the voltage readout and I'd have to wire in another. Is a part I can use that strictly doesn't exceed 500mA? The adafruit ones like to boast that they can supply up to 1A which is more than I need.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you're operating on the mistaken assumption which is that "putting less strain on the battery" by drawing less current will allow you to obtain more energy from it.  Unless you're drawing very much more current than the battery is designed for (very high multiples of its capacity), you will not see much difference in actual use time for your phone.  Additionally, the "current limiter" you propose to put inline can only work by lowering voltage to the load, which will waste a significant amount of power and likely cause the board to think the battery is dead well before it actually is.

Comment: Any current limiting circuitry on a 5v source will reduce the voltage available to charge your phone battery and I don't understand why you would do that.

Comment: @vir I'm not trying to obtain more energy, I'm trying to extend its usable life. Charging/discharging at higher rates over a long period of time compared to a smaller current causes the battery to degrade faster.

Comment: @GTElectronics how would it reduce voltage? If you have 5V 1.5A available then by dropping down to 5V 0.5A, the output power would not be exceeding the input. Is there not a simple way just to step down or limit the current?

Comment: If you can reduce the temperature rise in the battery cell by 10 deg. that should reduce the aging rate 50% during that period

Comment: But avoiding <10 and >90% SoC will do even more

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I would definitely keep it cool if I was able to, but since this is a cell phone, I don't have much control over the temperature during daytime use. That's why I'm looking at limiting current. I follow good charging practice as well; I try to stay between the 20% and 80% range.

Comment: Minimizing LED brightness reduces power significantly

Comment: The phone 'decides' how much current it wants to try to draw from the source. Limiting that current at the source would result in the charge simply being interrupted. Your charge board needs to tell your phone that it's only capable of supplying 500mA so that the phone doesn't try to draw more than that. If this were a somewhat standards-compliant device like an Android phone with USB then that would typically be done by some combination of resistors on the USB data lines, but I don't know how similar functionality is achieved on an iPhone.

Comment: @brhans I had no idea it functioned like this - thanks! With a little digging it seems like what you're saying is correct: https://learn.adafruit.com/minty-boost/icharging
Two of the pins on the board of the AudioMod above are D+ and D- which correspond to what the Adafruit page says. I may be able to adjust the output current simply by changing the resistor value. I'll get to it soon